# An equality in the proof of Krull theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading a proof of the following theorem:

> Let $A$ be a noetherian local ring, let $\mathfrak{m}$ be its maximal ideal and let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal of $A$. Then, it holds:
>   $$ \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left(\mathfrak{a}+\mathfrak{m}^n\right)=\mathfrak{a}.$$

During the proof it is states that it holds
$$\pi^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{a})^n\right)=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \pi^{-1}\left((\mathfrak{a} + \mathfrak{m}^n)/\mathfrak{a}\right)$$
where $\pi: A \to A/\mathfrak{a}$ is the natural quotient map.

This equality seems true to me, but I can't give a rigorous proof. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes from a more   general formula: if $\,\mathfrak{a,b,c}\,$ are ideals in a commutative ring $A$ such that $\,\mathfrak a\subset  \mathfrak{b}$ and $\,\mathfrak a\subset  \mathfrak{c} $, then in the quotient ring $A/\mathfrak a$, 
$$ \mathfrak{b/a}\cdot\mathfrak{c/a}=(\mathfrak{b\cdot c+a})/\mathfrak{a},$$
which is just an extension to quotient ideals of the definition of the product of elements in $A/\mathfrak a$:
$$(x+\mathfrak a)(y+\mathfrak a)=xy+ \mathfrak a.$$